# Cannot deploy SSAS Tabular Model in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssas-tabular

I am trying to deploy a Tabular Model in a local instance of SSAS, I am using SQL Server 2019 Developer edition, and data of the model comes from the example ContosoDW database which is stored in a local instance of SQL Server.

I had two scenarios:

1. First, I connected using "Impersonate service account", but when I deployed the model it just deployed the metadata and not the tables (no error showed), so there is no data in the model.
2. Then, I changed to "Impersonate account", but after the tables were imported their names turned light gray and I wasn't able to select them, very weird.

I think it has something to do with the impersonation options and how to configure them, I am learning SSAS Tabular with a book, but the impersonation weren't available at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using Windows credentials. Have you tried using Database credentials?

[image]